# Timer: Not start my method periodically every N seconds

Tags: kotlin

In my Kotlin project

I want start two independent timer.
First must run every 30 seconds.

Second must run every 20 seconds (start after 5 seconds).

I try this:

```
import kotlin.concurrent.schedule
import kotlin.concurrent.timerTask

  Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask { login() }, 1000, 30 * 1000)
  Timer().schedule(5_000) { Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask { updateState() }, 1000, 20 * 1000) }
```

First timer success run (**login**) periodically ever 20 seconds. Nice.

But seconds timer start only ONCE. Not run (**updateState**) periodically every 30 seconds.

Method **login** do sync http request. Method **updateState** also do sync http request.

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
    import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    import okhttp3.Request
    import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
    import okhttp3.Response

     fun login() {
        val loginRequestURL =
                    "${Config.instance.loginApiUrl}/importAPILogist.php"
            
            val requestToc= Request.Builder()
                    .url(loginRequestURL)
                    .get()
                    .build()
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
            val loginResponse: Response = httpClient.newCall(requestToc).execute() // sync request
    }
```

and another method:

```
   import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
    import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    import okhttp3.Request
    import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
    import okhttp3.Response
    
      fun updateOrdersState() {
            logger.info("updateOrdersState:")
            val someRequestURL = "${Config.instance.someApiUrl}/exportAPI"
            val requestOrderStateTocan = Request.Builder()
                    .url(someRequestURL)
                    .get()
                    .build()
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
            val tocanOrderStateResponse: Response = httpClient.newCall(requestOrderStateTocan).execute() // sync request
```

Method **updateState** can throw exception(java.net.SocketTimeoutException)

Maybe I need to catch exception when http request is not success? E.g.

```
Exception in thread "Timer-2" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
```

Comment: Works fine with simple `println` instead of `updateState()`. What's inside this function?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь do sync http request. I update my post

Comment: @МихаилНафталь Maybe I need to catch exception when http request is not success? Method updateState can throw exception

Comment: Don't know about your issue, but wanted to mention I don't think you need to wrap your second timer in another timer just to delay when it first starts. There's already a `delay` parameter for the `scheduleAtFixedRate` function.

Comment: You don't set any timeout in your `Request.Builder()`, so by default it's infinite (due to infinite callTimeout). 
See: https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-timeouts and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122236/okhttp3-never-timeout-on-slow-internet

Comment: @МихаилНафталь After I use try/catch in method updateOrdersState - the  problem is gone. And now success periodically start updateOrdersState every 30 sec

Comment: @МихаилНафталь Can't set timeout. Error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184378/okhttp4-4-0-cant-set-timeout-val-cannot-be-reassigned