# okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0: Can't set timeout for GET method: Val cannot be reassigned

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

Kotlin project

in build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0'
```

By default timeout is 10 sec. I want to change to 30 sec.

I try this:

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
import okhttp3.Response

 
  val requestToc = Request.Builder()
                    .url(loginURL)
                    .get()
                    .build()
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
            httpClient.connectTimeoutMillis = 30000; // error here
            val loginResponse: Response = httpClient.newCall(requestToc).execute()
```

But I get compile error:

```
Val cannot be reassigned
```

This also not working:

```
 val requestTocan = Request.Builder()
       .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // error here
       .url(loginTocanRequestURL)
                    .get()
                    .build()
```

I get error:

```
Unresolved reference: connectTimeout
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
```

Comment: I get error : Unresolved reference: connectTimeout

Comment: @a_subscriber idk, try to sync project with gradle files or invalidate cache

Answer (score 1):

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
httpClient.connectTimeoutMillis = 30000; // error here
```

To resolve val cannot be assigned issue just change val to var since val cannot be assigned a value.

And try doing this:

```
try {
    val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    builder.build()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    throw RuntimeException(e)
}
```

Comment: I was add my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185307/6813231

Answer (score -1):

I found solution:

```
private const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SEC = 30L
 val requestToc = Request.Builder()
                    .url(loginTocanRequestURL)
                    .get()
                    .build()
            val loginTocResponse = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build().newCall(requestToc).execute()
```